# Filter several columns at the same time and extract rows

Tags: awk, filter

I have a file like this:

```
[1]CHROM [2]POS [3]REF [4]ALT [5]GT_MA [6]GT_PA [7]GT_HI
1 13380 C G 0/1 0/1 0/1
1 13504 G A 0/0 0/0 0/0
1 17361 T * ./. 0/0 0/0
1 17365 C G ./. 0/0 0/0
1 17373 A G 0/0 ./. 0/0
1 17375 A G 0/1 0/1 1/1
1 17378 C T 1/1 0/1 1/1
1 17379 G A 0/0 ./. 0/0
1 17385 G A 0/0 ./. 0/0
1 17398 C A ./. ./. ./.
1 17403 A G 0/0 ./. ./.
1 17406 C T 0/0 ./. ./.
1 17407 G A 0/0 ./. ./.
1 17408 C G 0/0 ./. ./.
1 17452 C T 0/0 0/0 0/0
1 17478 C T 0/0 0/0 0/0
1 17479 G A 0/0 0/0 0/0
1 17483 C T 0/0 0/0 0/0
1 17484 G A 0/1 1/1 1/1
15 52640990 TAA TAAA,TAAAA,TA,T,TAAAAA 1/3 1/1 0/1
15 72252189 TAAA TAAAA,TAA,T,TAAAAA,TA,TAAAAAA 0/0 0/1 1/2
```

I would like to extract all rows with different combinations of values in $5, $6 and $7. For example $5=0/1,$6=0/1,$7=0/1; $5=0/1,$6=0/1,$7=1/1;$5=1/1,$6=0/1,$7=1/1 and $5=0/1,$6=1/1,$7=1/1.

Expected output:

```
   [1]CHROM [2]POS [3]REF [4]ALT [5]GT_MA [6]GT_PA [7]GT_HI
    1 13380 C G 0/1 0/1 0/1
    1 17375 A G 0/1 0/1 1/1
    1 17378 C T 1/1 0/1 1/1
    1 17484 G A 0/1 1/1 1/1
```

I tried to do an individual filter like this with no results.

```
awk -F '\t' '{ if(($5 = 0/1) && ($6 =0/1) && ($7 = 0/1)) { print }}' file1 > file2out
```

I am not sure if I could use awk to do this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does your sample now include lines that fail for the 2 answers you already got?

Answer (score 1):

This awk one-liner may help:

```
 awk '{s=$5 FS $6 FS $7}s!~"[.]/[.]" && s~/[1-9]/ && !a[s]++' file
```

output:

```
[1]CHROM [2]POS [3]REF [4]ALT [5]GT_MA [6]GT_PA [7]GT_HI
1 13380 C G 0/1 0/1 0/1
1 17375 A G 0/1 0/1 1/1
1 17378 C T 1/1 0/1 1/1
1 17484 G A 0/1 1/1 1/1
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly on the example but I have the same problem that I explain below to RavinderSingh13.

Comment: @Cris sorry I cannot understand what is the problem with your real data. You should edit your question, instead of adding more information in some comments. also, making examples is very helpful, but please try to make the example cover all your real scenarios. Breaking an answer by adding new requirement is always an easy thing to do. please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
 awk 'NR==1{print;next} !a[$5,$6,$7]++ && $0 !~ /\.\/\./'   Input_file
```

**EDIT:** Could you please try following once.

```
awk 'NR==1{print;next} !a[$5,$6,$7]++ && $0 !~ /\.\/\./ && ($0 !~ /[2-9]\// || $0 !~ /\/[2-9]/)'  Input_file
```

**EDIT1:** Let's say we have following Input_file.

```
cat Input_file
[1]CHROM [2]POS [3]REF [4]ALT [5]GT_MA [6]GT_PA [7]GT_HI
1 13380 C G 0/1 0/1 0/1
1 13504 G A 0/0 0/0 0/0
1 17361 T * ./. 0/0 0/0
1 17365 C G ./. 0/0 0/0
1 17373 A G 0/0 ./. 0/0
1 17375 A G 0/1 0/1 1/1
1 17378 C T 1/1 0/1 1/1
1 17379 G A 0/0 ./. 0/0
1 17385 G A 0/0 ./. 0/0
1 17398 C A ./. ./. ./.
1 17403 A G 0/0 ./. ./.
1 17406 C T 0/0 ./. ./.
1 17407 G A 0/0 ./. ./.
1 17408 C G 0/0 ./. ./.
1 17452 C T 0/0 0/0 0/0
1 17478 C T 0/0 0/0 0/0
1 17479 G A 0/0 0/0 0/0
1 17483 C T 0/0 0/0 0/0
1 17484 G A 0/1 1/1 1/1
1 17408 C G 0/0 ./. ./.
1 17452 C T 0/0 0/0 0/0
1 17478 C T 0/0 0/0 0/0
1 17479 G A 0/0 0/0 0/0
1 17483 C T 2/0 0/3 0/1
1 17484 G A 2/3 1/2 1/3
```

When I run code in EDIT it gives me following result.

```
awk 'NR==1{print;next} !a[$5,$6,$7]++ && $0 !~ /\.\/\./ && ($0 !~ /[2-9]\// || $0 !~ /\/[2-9]/)' Input_file
[1]CHROM [2]POS [3]REF [4]ALT [5]GT_MA [6]GT_PA [7]GT_HI
1 13380 C G 0/1 0/1 0/1
1 13504 G A 0/0 0/0 0/0
1 17375 A G 0/1 0/1 1/1
1 17378 C T 1/1 0/1 1/1
1 17484 G A 0/1 1/1 1/1
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly on the example. My mistake was not to said before that the original file which has 6998919 rows also contains values like 2/2, 3/0 and things like that. If I execute your command I obtain rows with values like 0/1 2/2 2/2 and I only want those I explained before. Another thing, do you mind to explain me your command so I could learn what it is doing. I'm new with awk!

Comment: @Cris, could you please check my EDIT now and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: It does still not work. Maybe I can do a second command to eliminate the undesired rows?

Comment: @Cris, I would like to request you to edit the sample data, I edited Input_file with my own values(based on your explanation) and it worked for it. Please add information into your post, if this doesn't help.